# How do I configure what connector maps to which speaker?

Tags: windows-7, speakers, 5.1

I have a [Medion Erazer X6811](http://www.lesnumeriques.com/ordinateur-portable/medion-erazer-x6811-md-97654-p10469) laptop running Windows 7. I'm trying to plug in [this 5.1 channel headphone](http://www.materiel.net/casque-multimedia/roccat-kave-solid-5-1-gaming-headset-49840.html) which works like 5.1 speakers.

I plugged the 3 connectors into the laptop, and set the computer to play in 5.1 in Realtek HD Audio Manager. When prompted, I configured the 1st front connector (green one) to be the front speaker, and the blue connector to be the side speaker.

*However*, the black connector maps to the front speaker *as well*, and pink maps to the subwoofer... so the "microphone" jack just disappears and I can't use it!

In summary, I can only set which speaker the green connector maps to, and not the other connectors. How can I configure every single connector to which speaker I want? Are there other solutions?

Comment: what about doing a [retasking](http://www.reaper-x.com/2012/02/13/how-to-remap-retasking-realtek-onboard-jacks-ports/)